# PySpark - get string position from list

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with column FN and a list of a subset of these column values
e.g.

```
    **FN**
    ABC
    DEF
    GHI
    JKL
    MNO
    
    List:
    ["GHI","DEF"]
```

I want to add a column to my dataframe where, if the column value exists in the List, I record the position within the list, that is my end DF

```
    FN     POS
    ABC
    DEF    1
    GHI    0
    JKL
    MNO
```

My code is as follows

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    l = ["GHI","DEF"]

    x = udf(lambda fn, p = l: p.index(fn), StringType())
    
    df = df.withColumn('POS', when(col("FN").isin(l), x(col("FN"))).otherwise(lit('')))
```

But when running I get a "J`ob aborted due to stage failure`" exception with a series of other exceptions, the only meaningful part being "`ValueError: 'JKL' is not in list`" (JKL being a random other column in my DF column)

If instead of "`p.index(fn)`" I just enter "fn", I get the correct column values in my new column, similarly if I use "`p.index("DEF")`", I get "1" back so individually these are working, any ideas why the exceptions?

TIA

---

EDIT: I have managed to go around this by doing an if-else within the lambda which is almost implying that it is executing the lambda prior to the "isin" check within the withColumn statement.
What I would like to know (other than whether the above is true), does anyone have a better suggestion on how to achieve this in a better manner?

Comment: please post expected output

Comment: You will have to use an if-else because you need to handle if the item is not in the list

Comment: create a map `map1 = expr(f"""map({','.join(f"'{e}',{i}" for i,e in enumerate(List))})""")` and then do `df.withColumn('POS', coalesce(map1[col('FN')],lit(''))).show()`. make sure to import expr, coalesce, lit from pyspark.sql.functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try. I have made a dataframe for the given list and join them.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

l = ['GHI','DEF']
m = [(l[i], i) for i in range(0, len(l))]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(m).toDF('FN', 'POS')
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(['POS','ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO'], "string").toDF('FN')

df1.join(df2, ['FN'], 'left').show()

+---+----+
| FN| POS|
+---+----+
|JKL|null|
|MNO|null|
|DEF|   1|
|POS|null|
|GHI|   0|
|ABC|null|
+---+----+
```